# How do I replace a numeric value with a string in Java

Tags: java, printing, output

I want to print "Two" in the place of 2 and "Four" in the place of 4 in Java within a FOR Loop while printing the numbers from 1 to 50.

**For example:**

> ```
> 1
> Two
> 3
> Four
> 5
> .
> .
> .
> 1Four
> 15
> .
> .
> .
> Two1
> TwoTwo
> Two3
> TwoFour
> .
> .
> .
> 50
> ```

Comment: please include the code you have attempted so far. Also, have a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 solution:

```
public class Play {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rangeClosed(1, 50).forEach(Play::twoOrFour);
    }

    public static void twoOrFour(long n) {
        String result = n + "";
        if (n % 10  == 2) {
            n /= 10;
            result = (n == 0 ? "" : n) + "two"; // the ternary exp: an ugly patch to get rid of the "0" in the first two cases
        } else if (n % 10 == 4) {
            n /= 10;
            result = (n == 0 ? "" : n) + "four";
        }
        System.out.print(result + " ");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 two 3 four 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1two 13 1four 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 2two 23 2four 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 3two 33 3four 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 4two 43 4four 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

**UPDATE**
In case you want to replace *any* occurrence of "2" with "two" and "4" with "four" the referenced method  can be even simpler:

```
public static void twoOrFour(long n) {
    String result = n + "";
    result = result.replaceAll("2", "two").replaceAll("4", "four");
    System.out.print(result + " ");
}
```

which will output:

```
1 two 3 four 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1two 13 1four 15 16 17 18 19 two0 two1 twotwo two3 twofour two5 two6 two7 two8 two9 30 31 3two 33 3four 35 36 37 38 39 four0 four1 fourtwo four3 fourfour four5 four6 four7 four8 four9 50
```

---

Or if to be even funkier - it can be done in a one-liner:

```
rangeClosed(1, 50).forEach((x)-> System.out.print((x + " ").replaceAll("2", "two").replaceAll("4", "four")));
```